# How do I find out if first character of a string is a number?

Tags: java, string

In Java is there a way to find out if first character of a string is a number?

One way is

```
string.startsWith("1")
```

and do the above all the way till 9, but that seems very inefficient.

Comment: I was going to mention the regex way, but I was afraid that if I did, you would be tempted to try it.

Answer (score 264, accepted):

```
Character.isDigit(string.charAt(0))
```

Note that [this will allow *any* Unicode digit](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char)), not just 0-9. You might prefer:

```
char c = string.charAt(0);
isDigit = (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
```

Or the slower regex solutions:

```
s.substring(0, 1).matches("\\d")
// or the equivalent
s.substring(0, 1).matches("[0-9]")
```

However, with any of these methods, you must first be sure that the string isn't empty. If it is, `charAt(0)` and `substring(0, 1)` will throw a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. `startsWith` does not have this problem.

To make the entire condition one line and avoid length checks, you can alter the regexes to the following:

```
s.matches("\\d.*")
// or the equivalent
s.matches("[0-9].*")
```

If the condition does not appear in a tight loop in your program, the small performance hit for using regular expressions is not likely to be noticeable.

Comment: Re: "you must first be sure that the string isn't empty" - true and more then that - you must also make sure its not null as if it is all the displayed methods will throw exceptions. You can either directly check ( e.g. `((null!=s) && Character.isDigit(s.charAt(0)) )` ) or use tricks like `Character.isDigit((s?s:"X").charAt(0)) `

Answer (score 8):

Regular expressions are very strong but expensive tool. It is valid to use them for checking if the first character is a digit but it is not so elegant :) I prefer this way:

```
public boolean isLeadingDigit(final String value){
    final char c = value.charAt(0);
    return (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
}
```

Comment: 1) `function` is not Java. 2) This only allows Arabic numerals, not Chinese, Indian, etc. That might be what you prefer, but it isn't specified in the question. 3) I already covered this exact solution in my answer four years ago.

Answer (score 1):

**IN KOTLIN :**

**Suppose** that you have a `String` like this :

```
private val phoneNumber="9121111111"
```

At **first** you should get the first one :

```
val firstChar=phoneNumber.slice(0..0)
```

At **second** you can check the first `char` that `return` a `Boolean` :

```
firstChar.isInt() // or isFloat()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
regular expression starts with number->'^[0-9]' 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile('^[0-9]');
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(String);

if(matcher.find()){

System.out.println("true");
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `{1,1}` suffix, which means that "the preceding pattern must appear between 1 and 1 times".  This means exactly the same as the pattern does on its own.

Comment: This solution does not work since String.matches and Pattern API tries to match complete string and not just first character

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this question and thought on contributing with a solution that does not use regex.

In my case I use a helper method:

```
public boolean notNumber(String input){
    boolean notNumber = false;
    try {
        // must not start with a number
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        double checker = Double.valueOf(input.substring(0,1));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        notNumber = true;           
    }
    return notNumber;
}
```

Probably an overkill, but I try to avoid regex whenever I can.

Answer (score -1):

To verify only first letter is number or character --
For number
Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0))   --return true

For character
Character.isLetter(str.charAt(0))   --return true