# Android simple calculator application

Tags: android

I'm new to android. I'm developing a simple calculator application.
There is some problem in my code. There is no syntax error.
When I run it, it gives some error. Written all code in a `try catch` but I'm still unable to catch it.

```
       b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            //char x = lbldisp.getText().toString().charAt(1);

        try
        {
            String x = lbldisp.getText().toString();
            if(x.charAt(0)=='0' && x.charAt(1)!='.')
            {
                    lbldisp.setText("1");
            }
            else
            {
                lbldisp.setText(x+"1");
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(Calculator.this,e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }
    });
```

Comment: what's the error you get after running it

Comment: how to see the actual error..

Comment: try to look into the LogCat window. You can filter the messages by clicking on the type of message you want to see

Comment: Actually I would like to know were the simplest place would be to start developing andriod software. I use Java and eclipse everyday which would make things very easy to start. On my old computer I downloaded a plug-in but it would seemed to work all that good for eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this string

```
 if(x.charAt(0)=='0' && x.charAt(1)!='.')
```

By this String

```
 if(x.charAt(0).equals("0") && x.charAt(1).equals("."))
```

You have Converted the value to String so try to use .equals Method.

Comment: there is no method like charAt(0).equals("0")

Comment: in errorlog it just showing like : thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)

Comment: You can try this then `        if(x.subSequence(0, 1).equals("0") && x.subSequence(1, 2).equals("."))
`

Comment: i m completely fresher for android...
can u give me a step for doing that... sry..

Comment: Just Check this site. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223052/how-do-i-find-out-if-first-character-of-a-string-is-a-number

Comment: actuly when i remove second condition from if then its work perfectly... bt when i add it.. its giving error..