# find the first character of a word

Tags: java

I have sentences starting with

1. ccccccccddkskdjskjdksjdfksjfkjs  sjfsjfksjjs

I want to see if the starting of the line I read is with a number and .
if yes I want to read the rest of the line.

How can I do that ?

I taught of reading the line to a

```
 string str.
str[0] and str [1].
str[1]= .

 x= Character.isDigit(string.charAt(0)); 
 if(x) { if (string.charAt(1)=='.') 
 { print ...I get a Exception
```

is there a easy way that I can check if str[0] is a number ..right now I am checking manually if it is 1 (or) 2...like that?

---

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class has `isDigit` method, which you can use as follows:

```
String str1 = "I start with letter";
boolean startWithDigit = Character.isDigit(str1.charAt(0));
// startWithDigit = false

String str2 = "1 start with digit";
boolean startWithDigit = Character.isDigit(str2.charAt(0));
// startWithDigit = true
```

Comment: Thank you this resolved by question..but I am having one more associated question before I close this:  ----Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)...I tried like you said x= Character.isDigit(string.charAt(0)); if(x)
          {
           if (line.charAt(1)=='.')
           {  I get that Exception

Comment: add the code in your question, it will be more clear to undestand.

Comment: before accessing index, always check `if (index < line.length())`

Answer (score 1):

```
String str="1. ccccccccddkskdjskjdksjdfksjfkjs sjfsjfksjjs";
char charAt = str.charAt(0);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m1 = p.matcher(""+charAt);
System.out.println(m1.matches());
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for the first character's ascii value.

```
 char x = str.charAt(0);
 if(x >= 48 && x <= 57)
 {
     // do whatever
 }
```

Comment: You can't subscript strings in Java like that

Comment: You can also use >= '0', <= '9'.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
boolean isANumber = false;
try{
  Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
  isANumber = true;
}catch(Exception e) {
}

//now isANumber is true if str[0] is a number
```

Comment: Char.isDigit(). Wont work if OP wants to check if it's a decimal (e.g. Double.parseDouble), or if it's not in base 10

Comment: I don't know what are you talking about. In your code you check only first character and try to parse it. So it is too much code, isDigit is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

`String string="ccccccccddkskdjskjdksjdfksjfkjs sjfsjfksjjs"`

`Character.isDigit(string.charAt(0));`

u can check ur value like this

for more detail see this one

[How do I find out if first character of a string is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223052/how-do-i-find-out-if-first-character-of-a-string-is-a-number)