# Converting the string phone number to integer

Tags: java, android

I am fairly inexperienced in Java as well as Android. I am trying to retrieve a phone number stored in one of the contacts of the android phone emulator. While I am successful to fetch it, the number has been returned in a string in a format like "(987) 654-3210".
I want to convert it to integer or long. How can I do that? If I use `Integer.parseInt(String number)`, it returns a `NumberFormatException`. Failed while tried using `Long.valueOf(String number)` too. What should I do then? I want it like "9876543210" without any braces or hyphens.

Comment: How are you going to handle phone numbers that start with a 0? or international numbers that start with a +?

Comment: You probably want to read [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1223064/1057429)

Comment: A phone number is not an integer, and should not be treated as such. Phone numbers, for example, might (locally) start with a 0 - mine does. As an integer, the leading 0 would be stripped.

Comment: You need to use regex to sanitize it rather than trying to parse it to a long or interger directly

Comment: What *possible* use would a phone number as an `int` or `long` be?

Comment: Check: [Extract digits from a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030928/extract-digits-from-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Phone numbers aren't integers.  There's not really even "groups of integers"; as @AMADANONInc points out 001 isn't the same as 1.  What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: well I dint think of the case of international numbers I agree,but my app deals with local numbers so I dont need to consider that.@PareshMayani your link helped me a lot.Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

using the `long` for storing number will be better

```
   String str="(987) 654-3210";
   String stt=str.replaceAll("\\D+","");
   long num= Long.parseLong(stt);
   System.out.println(num);
```

Answer (score 6):

This should be simple. You could use regex in java to do this like below

```
phoneStr = str.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```

This will delete the non digits from the string and give you only numbers. Then you can use

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(phoneStr);
```