# Decimal Format error

Tags: java

I have to convert string welcome into number format. But when I'm going to execute it throws exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "Welcome"
    at java.text.NumberFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sample.Sam.main(Sam.java:13)
```

package sample;

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class Sam {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String str="Welcome,@123";
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(str);

            System.out.println( df.parse(str));

    }

}
```

Comment: instead of decimal number you are parsing string.

Comment: Did you ever try to `1+welcome` in normal math? what should the result of this be? What do you think which number welcome represents?

Comment: I have string which contains decimal as well as character .I want to convert all these into decimal format.Is it possible  or not?/

Comment: @Kevin I havent tried

Comment: Everything is possible, but .. 
In that case you have to find just a numbers from that string

Comment: You need to clearly define what result you expect, for example for strings like "12ab34cd"

Answer (score 1):

The code you shared does no throw the Exception you copied...

Anyway, here is a code that will extract an integer from any string:

```
        String str="Welcome,@123";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "\\D*(\\d+)\\D*" );
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        if ( m.matches() )
        {
            int value = Integer.parseInt( m.group(1) );
            System.out.println( value );
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("no number found");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the format first with one string that is a valid [`DecimalFormat` pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) and then you can parse the real string:

```
String pattern = "'Welcome,@'0"; //0 is a placeholder, see the link for the others
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(pattern);

String input = "Welcome,@123";
System.out.println(df.parse(input)); //prints 123
```

As `,` is also a [placeholder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), I have had to quote the text `'Welcome,@'`.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible, but ..
In that case you have to find just a numbers from that string look  look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196830/what-is-the-easiest-best-most-correct-way-to-iterate-through-the-characters-of-a)

```
String s = "...stuff...";

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        char c = s.charAt(i);        
        //Process char
    }
```

For recognize if the char is number should be possible to use [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223052/how-do-i-find-out-if-first-character-of-a-string-is-a-number)

```
Character.isDigit(string.charAt(0))
```

So something like:

```
String s = "..ag123";
String numStr = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        char c = s.charAt(i);        
        if(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))){
              numStr += s.charAt(i);
         }
    }
 Integer.parseInt(numStr);
```

> For demimal you have to also recognize decimal (maybe also thousands?) separator :) But something in this way..

Btw you can still probably use *decimal formatter* but you need to set pattern for that (not sure if its possible like string pattern) - you cant find it in [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), Im not sure, but it will be something like `[^0123456789][123456789][separators][0123456789][^0123456789]` (missing nonmandatory and repeating there)