# How do i parse and differentiate '4 PM' or 'PM' in a javascript string value returns?

Tags: javascript

I am getting sometimes '4 PM' or 'PM' for the itemDate string. if itemDate has the value of 'PM' then I should not display anything to my HTML. If i get the value as '4 PM' then I should display that time value.

```
itemDate = '4 PM'

itemDate ='PM'
```

P.S : 4 PM is an example time string and it may be 12 AM too.

How do i do the parsing using javascript for my above request?

Comment: Surely you've noticed that the two cases have a different number of characters, no? Couldn't you use that?

Comment: You really are using a lot of frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

parseInt gets the value of an integer if it's the first thing in a string, it sounds very convenient in your case since you can just get the number, check if it's there, then act accordingly.

```
numeric = parseInt(itemDate);

if (typeof(numeric)=="number"){
    alert(itemDate);
}
```

You might also want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223052/how-do-i-find-out-if-first-character-of-a-string-is-a-number)